# How to combine Two for loops into one (in java)

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

Does anybody know to rewrite this code using only one for loop instead of two?

```
String message = "" ;
for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j<i; j++) {
        message = message + "*";
    }
    message = message + "\n";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Comment: why did you write this and why does it need to be rewritten?

Comment: Please note that when creating a `String` in a loop, it's more efficient to use the mutable `StringBuilder` type (and, if possible, set a sensible starting size for the buffer).

Comment: I disagree that this question leads to answers which simply offer personal opinion. The question asks for code which is functionally equivalent to nested for loops, and each answer given can be tested for correctness. Opinion does not play a part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code satisfies the requirement:

```
String message = "" ;
String m = "";
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    message = message + m + "\n";
    m = m + "*";
}
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, message);
```

Comment: sorry I'm a rookie .. should i just click on the check mark on the right ? if so i just did ..thanks again

Answer (score 2):

```
for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
    message += "*******".substring(0, i) + "\n";
}
```

also you should use a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: @Durandal i saw as well and corrected it :)

Comment: Why more than eight stars in the source string when `i` never goes above a value of `7`?

Comment: Because I didnt feel like counting them exactly.

Answer (score 2):

One way:

```
String message = "";
String line = "";

for(int i=0; i<8; i++) {
    message = message + line + "\n";
    line = line + "*";
}
```

Comment: so the shape is supposed to be a half pyramid and that's why the second loop is there

Comment: I think you need to change this to `message = message + line + "\n";` otherwise you start off with two newlines, and the OP's nested loop does not.

Comment: yours output is completely different so its supposed to be a half pyramid thats why the second loop is there

Comment: Sorry I accidentally used "/n" instead of "\n"

Answer (score 1):

So, as this is a post of funny solutions, taste mine:

```
        String message = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
            message = "*\n" + message.replaceAll("\n", "*\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I'll leave it to the reader to figure out if, how and why this works :)

```
    String message = "";
    int n = 8;
    int s = (int) Math.round((n + 1) * (n * 0.5));
    int j = 0, l = 1;
    for (int i=0; i < s; ++i) {
        int k = Integer.signum(j - i) ^ 1;
        message += "*\n".charAt(k);
        l += k;
        j += (l * k);
    }
```

Comment: You are crazy, I like you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another one, short and funny :)

```
    String message = "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        message = message + "*" + message.substring(message.length() - i - 1);
    }
```